# Passing Messages Between .NET App and UWP App

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-core

I have a UWP application and I want to communicate with .NET application that uses non-UWP supported code.I know how to use full trust application and start and pass parameters to .NET application, but how do I return back messages etc. from .NET application to UWP app like a normal function call operates.

Comment: Here is a simple for your reference.https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples

Comment: The reference is about converting the .NET app to UWP app. But my problem is communicating between the .NET app and UWP App.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample

Comment: Thanks a lot @jerry it is working !!!

Comment: @jerry can you post an answer out?